# Evaluating $\int_{} \frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx$ via integration by parts

Tags: integration

$\int_{} \frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx$

I am having trouble picking the correct $u/dv$ before integrating by parts. I felt like L.I.A.T.E. did not really help me here...

This is what I tried, but it ended up with integration spiraling into an endless evaluation of an integral...

$$
\begin{align}
u &= (1 + 2x)^2 & dv &= xe^{2x}dx \\
du &= 2(1+2x)dx & v &= \frac{1}{2}x^2 \frac{1}{2}e^{2x} \\
 &= 2 + 4xdx & &= \frac{1}{4}x^2e^{2x}
\end{align}
$$

Am I at least correct in choosing the right $u/du$ values? That is all I really want to know, if I am allowed to choose the $u/du$ like how I did

Comment: Check $du$. You've made an error when applying the chain rule. Recall: $$[(f(x))^n]'=nf'(x)(f(x))^{n-1}$$

Comment: oops, you're right. Should be $du = 1(1+2x)dx$, thanks!

Comment: @EvanKim Actually, it should be $du=4(1+2x)dx$.

Comment: oh, yes you're right. I am not thinking right anymore lol, time to take a break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $u=xe^{2x}$, $\text dv=\dfrac{\text dx}{(1+2x)^2}$.

**Result:**
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}}{8x+4} + C$$

**EDIT: More steps.**

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2} \ \text dx &=& \left|\begin{array}{2}
  u=xe^{2x} & \text dv=\dfrac{\text d x}{(1+2x)^2} \\
  \text du = (1+2x)e^{2x}\ \text dx & v=-\dfrac{1}{2(1+2x)}
\end{array}\right| = \\
&=& -\frac{xe^{2x}}{2(1+2x)} + \frac{1}{2} \int e^{2x}\ \text dx = \\
&=&-\frac{xe^{2x}}{2(1+2x)} + \frac{1}{4}e^{2x} + C = \\
&=& e^{2x}\left( -\frac{x}{2(1+2x)}+\frac{1}{4} \right) + C = \boxed{\frac{e^{2x}}{8x+4} + C}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Hey, I know you answered this almost a week ago...I have tried for HOURS to try to work this out given your hint and have not been successful yet :(

Comment: @EvanKim There you go. I added more steps.

Comment: Thank you! How did you simplify the last line? I am getting the wrong fraction when trying to combine the common denominators in the parentheses

Comment: @EvanKim $$\cdots=\frac{-2x+1+2x}{4(1+2x)}$$

Comment: Thank you, your whole process seemed like a good way of getting through all of the spots that were tricky to me (and also filled in a lot of my blank spots to make more sense)

Comment: @EvanKim You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$u=1+2x$:

$$\require{cancel}
\int\frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}\,dx=
\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{(1+2x-1)e^{2x+1-1}}{(1+2x)^2}\frac{d}{dx}(1+2x)\,dx=\\
\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{(u-1)e^{u-1}}{u^2}\,du=
\frac{1}{4e}\int\left(\frac{ue^{u}}{u^2}-\frac{e^{u}}{u^2}\right)\,du=\\
\frac{1}{4e}\int\left(\frac{e^{u}}{u}-\frac{e^{u}}{u^2}\right)\,du=
\frac{1}{4e}\left(\int e^{u}\frac{1}{u}\,du-\int e^{u}\frac{1}{u^2}\,du\right)=\\
\frac{1}{4e}\left(\int e^{u}(\ln{u})'\,du+\int e^{u}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)'\,du\right)=\\
\frac{1}{4e}\left(e^{u}\ln{u}-\int e^{u}\ln{u}\,du+\frac{e^u}{u}-\int e^{u}\frac{1}{u}\,du\right)=\\
\frac{1}{4e}\left(e^{u}\ln{u}-\int e^{u}\ln{u}\,du+\frac{e^u}{u}-\int e^{u}(\ln{u})'\,du\right)=\\
\frac{1}{4e}\left(\cancel{e^{u}\ln{u}}-\cancel{\int e^{u}\ln{u}\,du}+\frac{e^u}{u}-\cancel{e^{u}\ln{u}}+\cancel{\int e^{u}\ln{u}\,du}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{4e}\frac{e^u}{u}=\frac{1}{4e}\frac{e^{1+2x}}{1+2x}=\frac{e\cdot e^{2x}}{4e(1+2x)}=\frac{e^{2x}}{4+8x}+C.
$$

[Wolfram Alpha check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(x*e%5E(2x))%2F((1%2B2x)%5E2)%20dx)

Comment: Where did the $\frac{1}{4}$ come from? I see that you used the substitution rule, but am having trouble understanding all of your algebra

Comment: $$\frac{1}{4}(1+2x-1)\frac{d}{dx}(1+2x)=\frac{1}{4}2x\cdot2=\frac{1}{4}4x=x$$